# Rendering an image stored localy with v-html in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

i am trying to render an image with the v-html directive, my images are stored in a folder [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OGVj.png)

And there is my code:

```html
<template lang="html">
  <b-container fluid>
    <b-row>
      <b-col cols="2" offset="5" v-html="renderCorps">
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
  renderCorps(item){
      var link = '"../../assets/images/activite-red.png"';
      return "<img src= "+link+">";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

it seems that something's going wrong with the path and i can't got it, any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack would not reference to dynamic image links, not inlined into href of image.
Use this [plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to copy images to public folder